# Key binding in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have problem with key bindings. I can't set key for "+". Can somebody help me, what should I write in xaml and what should I write in .cs ???

Comment: Could you show what you're trying already?

Answer (score 2):

Keybindings can be set at the `Window` level, so in XAML you'd add...

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="YourCommand" Key="+" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I assume you know how to provide a `Command` with `Window.CommandBinding`.

Comment: In .xaml.cs file I wrote - public static RoutedCommand AddCommand = new RoutedCommand();

Comment: in another dll I wrote for command binding(I also used command bindings, which work normally) :
 private void AddCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void AddExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExecuteOperation();
            _prevOperation = _math.Add;

            e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: In xaml I wrote as you said. After debugging, there is not any error, but exception is trown: 
Cannot convert string 'AddCommand' in attribute 'Command' to object of type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand'. CommandConverter cannot convert from System.String.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Input.KeyBinding' in markup file 'WPF Calculator;component/window1.xaml' Line 14 Position 21.

Comment: I am new in this sphere, I need some advices :(((